# Даёт ли "кэширование" длины массива прирост производительности в цикле for?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Имею ввиду такую конструкцию:

```
var length = arr.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
}
```

У меня получилась разница в разы:

```js
arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
 arr[i] = i;
}

var b = Date.now();
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
}
console.log(Date.now() - b);

var b = Date.now();
var length = arr.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
}
console.log(Date.now() - b);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q1tLcyap/

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42462/discussion-on-question-by-khipster-------).

Answer (score 4):

Если тело цикла не пустое - то любой возможный прирост производительности будет измеряться самое большее в единицах процентов.

А если в теле цикла есть работа с DOM - то прироста от длины массива вы не заметите никак.

Не экономьте на спичках. Пишите такой код, который проще читать.

Comment: вопрос, вероятно, про внутренности реализации JS-движка: длина массива там каждый раз вычисляется, или же хранится во внутренней «переменной», которая изменяется только при добавлении/удалении новых элементов?

Comment: Хотя в реальной ситуации так оно и есть, но либо в тесте с вымышленными условиями я где-то "накосячил", либо `arr.length` всё же работает в 3-4 раза быстрее, чем `var length`. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/88n1dp3o/).

Comment: @Regent: Ну так у глупого оптимизатора текущей версии Chrome при некешированной длине срабатывает распознавание паттерна цикла и врубается оптимизация.

Comment: @Regent так вроде надо в начале заполнить массив...и потом смотреть......https://jsfiddle.net/6wm45b33/1/

Comment: У меня получилась разница в разы: https://jsfiddle.net/q1tLcyap/

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я исходил из предположения что `.length` - это просто поле, и потому ничего не зависит от реального размера массива. Видимо, напрасно.

Comment: @Khipster а вы `arr = [];` замените на `var arr = [];`, и разница "в разы" исчезнет.

Comment: кстати вот в [этом ответе](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5753407/2881286) говорится что на [этой строке](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/objects.cc#L7235) кэшируется длина массива

Comment: @Regent Поймал ты меня :))) Ладно, кстати а почему так получается?

Comment: @Khipster могу предположить, что доступ к полю объекта `window` (в частности, к `window.arr` в вашем примере) занимает ощутимо больше времени, чем к простой переменной.

Comment: @Regent Да, тоже так подумал. В итоге когда мы постоянно тащим такой объект для измерения длины его свойства - мы и получаем разницу в разы. Что собственно свидетельствует о том, что V8 ничего не кэширует.

Comment: @Khipster отчего же? Пример с `var arr` свидетельствует о том, что длина массива таки когда-то и как-то но кэшируется (не высчитывается каждый раз при её запросе). А вот объекты - нет. Поэтому если массив "хранится" в переменной, то разницы особо не видно. А если добираться до массива - дело затратное, то кэширование его самого или его длины в переменной помогает.

Comment: @Regent Какой смысл не кэшировать свойства объектов но кэшировать переменные? По-моему движок очень быстро считает arr.length, ведь и с var arr пример c кэшированием чуточку быстрее, а этого не было бы если бы движок сам по себе кэшировал длину.

Comment: @Khipster давайте так: когда дело доходит до десятков миллионов итераций, имеет смысл вынести длину в отдельную переменную. Если речь про массив на сто или тысячу элементов, то разницы в производительности не будет. В этом случае выносить в переменную имеет смысл только если это улучшает читаемость кода. В `for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)`, например, в таком случае нет смысла создавать новую переменную и тратить на неё строку кода. Так что всё зависит от ситуации.

Comment: @Regent Ну вот ещё, каждый раз продумывать что и где там перебирает этот for, куда проще выработать определённый стиль кода и его придерживаться.

Comment: @Khipster это как "С самого начала у меня была какая-то тактика и я её придерживался"? Вы можете использовать любые правила для стиля кода - право ваше. Но многие правила имеют исключения, и про них не стоит забывать. В любом случае, к вопросу это уже не относится.

Comment: @Regent С самого начала у меня была какая-то тактика и я её придерживался

Answer (score 1):

### Забавные результаты

Код теста:

```js
let arr = [];

for (var e = 0; e < 1000; e++)
  arr.push(e);

function run(count) {
  let f = [],
    s = [];
  count = parseInt(count) || 0;

  for (let e = 0; e < count; e++) {
    let start = Date.now();

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
      null;

    f.push(Date.now() - start);
  }

  for (let e = 0; e < count; e++) {
    let start = Date.now(),
      length = arr.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
      null;

    s.push(Date.now() - start);
  }

  return {
    first: f,
    second: s
  };
}

[1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000].forEach(item => {
  let tmp = run(item);

  console.info(`Размер массива: ${arr.length}\nКоличество итераций: ${item}\n\nБез кэширования (среднее): ${tmp.first.reduce((a, e) => a += e) / tmp.first.length}\nС кэшированием (среднее): ${tmp.second.reduce((a, e) => a += e) / tmp.second.length}`);
});
```

*Chrome 51*:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Firefox 47*:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно, лису выгоднее кэшировать только небольшие структуры, чем больше массив, тем меньше пользы (даже в минус по пользе ушло).
Хром так же, но кэширует эффективнее, видимо.

---

**Вывод**:
Оптимизация - сложная штука. Она вроде есть, а вроде и только минус :)
В первую очередь - пишите **человекопонятный код**!
Экономия человекочасов на разборе - А как оно работает? - перекроет -4 миллисекунды оптимизации.
Потом уже можно думать как оптимизировать доступ к длине и прочее.
Такие большие вещи нужно по небольшим кускам разделять.

Comment: А если запустить эти измерения независимо несколько раз, то обнаружите, что время каждый раз разное и иногда победитель кардинально меняется.

Comment: Я запускал это несколько раз, нагрузка примерно одна (фотошоп, шторм, куча вкладок, GTA5 и по мелочи), примерно одно и то же было, кардинально ничего не менялось, +-2. Профессиональный и полный тест сделать не знаю как, но это тоже неплохо. Вроде бы.

Comment: Вы измеряете не то что хотите.

Comment: @Arnial, возможно. Только "измеряете".

Comment: В обоих случаях получение длины будет происходить вне цикла.
[статься от разработчика v8 на эту тему](http://mrale.ph/blog/2012/12/15/microbenchmarks-fairy-tale.html), также можете [сами проверить что реально будет делать браузер](http://mrale.ph/irhydra/2/#)

Comment: @Arnial, интересно, почитаю, благодарю. Я не тестер, как правильно проверять не знаю, поэтому цифры может и не точны, зато относительно друг друга довольно наглядны ИМХО.

Answer (score 0):

Раньше был тест где сравнивались все варианты перебора , назывался он [foreach-vs-loop](https://jsperf.com/foreach-vs-loop) , сейчас он недоступен но можно поискать по картинкам, в кратце, разницы нет, с кэшированием даже получалось чуть-чуть медленнее, что удивительно обратный `for` был быстрее чем прямой
ps: можно найти сохранённую копию, например на [яндексе](http://hghltd.yandex.net/yandbtm?fmode=inject&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjsperf.com%2Fforeach-vs-jquery-each%2F26&tld=ru&lang=en&la=1450184320&tm=1468311795&text=foreach-vs-for&l10n=ru&mime=html&sign=0af0bca7e81b2b0aee41b2d9806653ab&keyno=0) , это конечно не полный тест но интересующее в вопросе есть.
ps: удивляет скорость *assign in loop declaration* , я бы даже сказал не удивляет в поражает.

Comment: for loop(cached) ненамного быстрее :P

Comment: тут статистическая погрешность на самом деле влияет, в реальности все движки итак кэшируют, и к стати сейчас обратный for перестал быть быстрее, видимо дооптимизировали V8 :)

Comment: Не, ну обратный for это уже перебор :D